# Exclude posts which have any term in a certain taxonomy from the query

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I have a custom taxonomy, and for a certain query I am doing, I want to retrieve all posts which **do not** have any terms of that taxonomy assigned (for example, they are *tag-less*).

At the beginning I thought to do the following:

```
$tax_slugs = wp_list_pluck( get_terms('my_tax'), 'slug' );
$query_args['tax_query'] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'my_tax',
    'terms'    => $tax_slugs,
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
);
```

However, what this does is looking for posts with `my_tax` taxonomy, *excluding* all of them, which is obviously not ideal.

The only other solution I've thought of is by merging two queries, but I'd rather keep the number of queries at a minimum, since this is already a secondary query.